# Contact name missing from text messages

Tags: ios, contacts, software-update, text

Contacts are saved but since the update, when I get a text no name appears only the telephone number? But I open the text, the name appears at the top, just when initial text notification comes through

Comment: I've seen that too - but I think it may do it only the first time from a contact; after that it seems OK [I wasn't really paying attention, that's just how in recollection it may have happened]

Comment: Please edit this to explain what version of iOS - and build perhaps since one person thinks this is a bug that might get fixed on a new build/version

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what your country is but we had a similar issue in mine. The cause was that number format inside the country is different from the international format that most operators use when sending messages or doing calls. For example, in the country we have 8-926-1234567 and international number is +7-926-1234567. In some old iOS versions iPhone could not recognize these numbers as the same.

The solution was simple: always use international number for all contacts. Try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in iOS 9. Even with iOS 9 being in public beta for 4 months, there will still be bugs, so restart your iPhone (accomplIshed by holding the lock button and home button together until an Apple logo appears) and if that doesn't work then hopefully iOS 9.0.1 will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. A fairly fundamental bug for any phone, let alone one that cost over £700.

Please add your voice to this discussion and maybe Apple will finally take notice.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7229314?start=0&tstart=0

N.B. Ignore any advice that starts with 'First you need to delete all your old messages...'